# Allow a command line tool to create files using ofstream

Tags: c++, xcode, ofstream

I'm having some trouble using ofstream with a command line tool.

Say, for example, I would like to create a file that creates a file, and writes to it. The code I would use is:

```
ofstream outfile("myfile.txt");
outfile << "Hello World!";
outfile.close();
```

This works when I build it in Xcode. However, when I run it from Terminal, the file does not write. Am I doing something wrong, or is it something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: shouldn't it be `outfile("myfile.txt")`?

Comment: Assuming the double quotes were lost in copying, do you have write permissions on the current directory when you call the program from the terminal?

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing out the missing double quotation marks - I've fixed it. I also have write permissions to the current directory in Terminal.

Comment: Sorry, though it was the other way around (runs from terminal, not from Xcode). I see nothing wrong with the code. That should write to the current working directory, whenever that is when you actually run it. ex: `/path/to/executable/binary` should create your file in `.`, the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is in access rights.  Try:
sudo executable